# DIV not wrapping around controls inside

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Morning,

I am trying to do something so simple but for some reason my parent div is not wrapping around its controls.

[image]
The yellow small box is my parent DIV and the controls (Label, DropDownList) are inside that div, but as you can see the box isnt wrapping around them.

```
<div id="divCUSTOMER_INSURED_PARTY__TITLE_ID__1" runat="server" class="form-group questionRow"
    clientidmode="Static">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CUSTOMER_INSURED_PARTY__TITLE_ID__1"
        CssClass="control-label col-md-4">Title</asp:Label>
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group fixedControl">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CUSTOMER_INSURED_PARTY__TITLE_ID__1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"
            ListTable="LIST_TITLE" TopItems="">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <div class="help">
        </div>
        <div class="validator">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqCUSTOMER_INSURED_PARTY__TITLE_ID__1" runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="CUSTOMER_INSURED_PARTY__TITLE_ID__1"           Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="0"
                ValidationGroup="">
<div class="alert alert-danger">Please Complete.</div>
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "divCUSTOMER_INSURED_PARTY__TITLE_ID__1" is the parent div and everything else is wrapped inside.

Here is my CSS Code:

```
.form-group {margin-bottom: 0px}
.questionRow {padding: 3px; border: 0px none #FFF; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}
```

Does anyone know the reason for this?

ANSWER:

At the bottom of my parent DIV i added:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

In my CSS i added this:

```
.clear{clear:both}
```

This made the DIV correctly wrap around everything.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you tried clear?

Comment: @Amit Sorry, could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: or simply create a demo, so we can help better

Comment: I have tried the .clear{clear: both} that was suggested and it worked. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `clear` before closing yellow div

HTML:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow: auto` to the `.questionRow` class.

Comment: I added overflow:auto to the class and it worked, but i then get a problem with my tooltip as it doesn't show on hover.